# Scenekit Error: Inconsistency in scene graph found in C3DNode finalize - clueless

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have been working on a ARKit/ SceneKit app. I have been getting this particular **Scenekit** Error, which doesn't crash the app right away, however on repeated usage after a certain point, the app crashes.

> [SceneKit] Error: inconsistency in scene graph found in C3DNode
>   finalize

I have used the usual ways to create nodes and remove them from parent, etc. And more importantly, I have created several other modules (within the same app) without ever encountering such an error. I have been trying to close this issue for the past two days, however I couldn't get any clue.

Following are what I have tried:

- Checking *allocations* of `SCNNodes` (in Instruments) hoping rather that
  some nodes would persist, but this is not the case.
- Removing any method which changes the `SCNMaterial` of a node, hoping the possibly *changes in material property* might have some
  issue.
- Removing any node which are being regenerated in my app, hoping that possibly generating *lot of nodes* might create this issue.
- Comparing this module against other modules within my app, which are based on the same logic to check whether I might have changed something within this module. But to no avail.
- Removing all logics of `AddAudioNode()` and in fact all audio nodes themselves, since I saw in my allocations within `Instrument.trace` that they are persistent and are not being removed on node removal. But this also didn't help.

Granted this module is supposedly more complex with incrementally more number of nodes, however I am not able to understand what direction to strike in to investigate this Error.

I have not found anything existing on the net/ SO on this issue. The only option I am left with to raise a TSI with Apple, though it would cost me 1 TSI, which I have left, and they are expensive, these TSIs! Hence, I really hope if someone is able to throw some light on this and let me know how to approach this bug, it would be very helpful. Anything you require from the code, I can add in, but then the whole codebase is pretty humongous to post here. Hence, snippets as much as applicable.

Comment: You have some more work to do before someone else will be able to help you, either here or through an Apple TSI (the TSI's are cheap BTW, much less than hiring a consultant!). At the very least, show us the code that crashes. If you don't know the line that crashes, that's some isolation you can do first. If you're not sure, try making a screen recording and/or recording an XCUITest. I'd also try running with Address Sanitizer and Thread Sanitizer. You're on the right track: keep removing things until it no longer crashes. But you'll have to get it down to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @HalMueller After all kinds of investigations into the issue, I had to raise a TSI. From their response it seems to be a bug with them. However, they have asked me to send over minimum reproducible code to them for further diagnosis. Thanks Hal. Help much appreciated. I will keep posted if something important comes back from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encounted this error when my code was trying to remove nodes on a background thread, so I recommend checking that you are on the main thread with `Thread.isMainThread` when debugging to ensure you are on the main thread.  Something like `SCNAction.run(block)` actually launches your code in a background thread, which is where I encountered this error.  Basically the background thread removed from parent while at the same time the main thread was trying to do something with the node, which cause the scene graph to change before the node finished its process.

Comment: This sounds like a real plausible thing going on. Let me please get back to you on this. Appreciate the observation.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the issue was.

Comment: For reference as to why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700071/scenekit-threads-what-to-do-on-which-thread

Comment: Hmm according to that answer,  we should be running the actions on the rendering thread.  I need to check if the run action runs on the rendering thread, because then that answer may be wrong.

Comment: Yep, hence SCNTransaction is the best way to go. I was having the issue mainly when there were a plenty of SCNNodes and were being removed from the parent. In general, even it removeFromParentNode() is called from Main Thread, rendering thread handles the request itself, but in rarest cases esp. where there are several nodes it might crash. Best way to go ahead with atomic updates using SCNTransaction. Hence, finally using your answer as well as the one referred, I feel good.

Comment: I wouldn't your answer is wrong, just partially correct. Other than rendering thread, main thread is best positioned to handle this.

Comment: No, I mean the answer to the post you shared

Comment: From the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransaction it appears all sccenekit stuff runs on rendering thread. "SceneKit creates a transaction automatically whenever you modify the objects in a scene graph".

Comment: Hmmm, I don’t see that it is automatically ran on rendering thread, because transactions with duration of 0 are fired immediately.   Will have to play around more.