# SCNSceneRendererDelegate Update function not called from UI thread in MAUI

Tags: ios, .net, maui, scenekit, arkit

In MAUI, I am trying to do a `HitTest` in the `Update` function of the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` class.
The problem is that the `Update` function is called from a background thread which results in a `UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.` error.

I can wrap the call in a `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` call but i suspect that leads to performance issues because the Update function is called many times per second.

I already found [SceneKit - Threads - What to do on which thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700071/scenekit-threads-what-to-do-on-which-thread) but there was no proper solution.

As far as i remember i didnt have that problem in Xamarin so Im wondering what changed.

Comment: Since the user interface elements must run on the application's main thread, you may need call the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` in the main thread:`MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` and there's a [similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/553553/xamarin-forms-uikit-consistency-error-for-ios-only) according to the error message, you can refer to it.

Comment: Yes, using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` inside of `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` resolves the error message but i suspect that it leads to performance issues.

Comment: How can U determine it's a performance issue as `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` is called many times per second can't prove that.